# Wordpress Caption Broken

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am currently learning how to make a wordpress theme but somehow the caption tag is broken. For some reason it adds quotation marks to the code and the code is being displayed on the page itself. I understand that this affected WP 3.4 and later but I have not been using any plugins etc. Can I ask what is the correct way to solve this problem? Thanks. My Wordpress version is 3.6.

[image: Problem]

This is my loop to display the posts.

```
 <div role="main">
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="post-header">
     <a class="post-header" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></header>
     <time class="post-date"><p> <?php the_time('l, j M Y')?></p></time>
    <p class="post-content"><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p>
    <!-- put post class tags in -->
    <div class="tags-container">
    <?php $tags = get_the_tags();
    if( $tags ) : ?>
      <?php foreach( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
       <span class="tags <?php echo $tag->slug; ?>"><i class="icon icon-tag"></i><a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a></span>
      <?php } ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>      
    </article>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I don't see the caption shortcode in your loop. Did you include it inside your content field?

Comment: I don't quite get you.the caption code was generated by wordpress itself. on visual it looks fine but on the page itself, the problem occurs.

Comment: instead of visual mode, click on the 'Text' tab. paste that code somewhere for us to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>` with `<?php the_content(); ?>`.

I believe `get_the_content()` returns the raw content from the DB and does not run it through the normal filters that are applied to `the_content()` such as `wpautop` and `do_shortcode` (although the [WP Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) is not clear about this).

Unless you have a specific reason to use `get_the_content()` (like passing it into a function or filter) you should use `the_content()` which automatically echos the content and runs it through WP's default content filters.

If that does not solve your problem, most likely a plugin or custom theme function is preventing the shortcode from being parsed.

edit: verified that `get_the_content()` returns unfiltered post content.  Curiously this is not directly stated in the get_the_content() function reference but instead is in the [function reference for the_content()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) (Alternative Usage section).

Comment: so that was the problem. need to read up on the difference between get_the_content() and the_content(). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you are custom rendering the content.  Once again, not using the `the_content()` function.

If you can't or don't want to use `the_content()`, you could always wash the outputted content with the `strip_shortcodes()` function.  Like so:

```
$content = $article->post_content;
$content = strip_shortcodes($content);
```